# Rust ndarray: iterate over array in column order

Tags: rust, audio, rust-ndarray

I have a 2D array with shape (2,  N), from the [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/) crate, of i16 audio samples (a stereo (2-channel) audio clip). The standard way that these values are written to a file is in column-major order, so every even entry belongs to channel 1 / row 0 and the odd elements correspond to channel 2 / row 2.

I'm sure there's a way of doing this without using column-major ordering, but it seems like this shouldn't be the case/necessary and that there is likely an idiomatic way to do this using the in-built crate functionality.

The crate documentation explicitly states that `iter` and `iter_mut` use row-major ordering, without the option of changing it.

Is there a way to achieve this in the ndarray crate, or do I need to do my own column order iteration?

Comment: "I'm sure there's a way of doing this without using column-major ordering" I don't know what you mean by that, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I completly understood what you are trying to do, but I think you want either this

```rust
for row in data.columns() {
    for val in row.iter() {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

or that which is the other way round:

```rust
for column in data.rows() {
    for val in column.iter() {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

where `data` is your array.

Here is a link to [rustexplorer](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#%2F*%0A%5Bdependencies%5D%0Andarray%20%3D%20%220.15.0%22%0A*%2F%0Ause%20ndarray%3A%3Aprelude%3A%3A*%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20data%20%3D%20array!%5B%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B4%2C%205%2C%206%5D%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20row%20in%20data.columns()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20val%20in%20row.iter()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22---%20The%20other%20way%20round%20---%22)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20column%20in%20data.rows()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20val%20in%20column.iter()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20val)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A).

P.S.: I think it would have benefited the question if you had provided example code and the expected output.